# Getting status, body, and headers from node-libcurl

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, libcurl, node-libcurl

I have the following code in a Node.js application:

```
var curlStatus = ""; 
var curlBody = ""; 
var curlHeaders = ""; 
var curlInfo = curl.on('end', function( statusCode, body, headers){
    curlStatus = statusCode; 
    curlBody = body; 
    curlHeaders = headers; 

    //this.close(); 
    return {status: curlStatus, body: curlBody, headers: curlHeaders}; 
}); 

curl.on('error', function(){
    console.log("CURL ERROR");
}); 

curl.perform();
```

Placing a breakpoint on `return {status: curlStatus, body: curlBody, headers: curlHeaders};` shows that the `body`, `headers`, and `statusCode` are being successfully populated.  However, putting a breakpoint after `curl.perform()` shows that the `curlStatus`, `curlBody`, and `curlHeaders` variables are still empty strings. How do I pass the information to the parent function?

Comment: The execution in javascript is not essentially sequential (better to think that way), the callback function passed into `curl.on('end')` is executed at a much latter time after `curl.perform`. Thus a breakpoint just right after `curl.perform()` won't show you anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to javascript and asynchronous problem.

When you do `curl.perform();`, the request will start but isn't yet done, that why your variable `curlX` are not yet populated.
Once the request is done, the callback that you defined with `url.on('end', function...` is called, and you will populate these variables.

Comment: Ah okay, so theoretically I could use something like a promise to fix this, right?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap everything in a Promise and get your results. Or write the next step of you script inside your callback.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the addon.

If you have issues with the async interface, or need a synchronous solution, I've added support for `Easy` handles some time ago, they are used almost exactly like the [libcurl easy interface](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html).

```
var Easy = require( 'node-libcurl' ).Easy,
    Curl = require( 'node-libcurl' ).Curl,
    url = process.argv[2] || 'http://www.google.com',
    ret,
    ch;

ch = new Easy();

ch.setOpt( Curl.option.URL, url );

ch.setOpt( Curl.option.HEADERFUNCTION, function( buf, size, nmemb ) {

    console.log( 'HEADERFUNCTION: ' );
    console.log( arguments );

    return size * nmemb;
});

ch.setOpt( Curl.option.WRITEFUNCTION, function( buf, size, nmemb ) {

    console.log( 'WRITEFUNCTION: ' );
    console.log( arguments );

    return size * nmemb;
});

ret = ch.perform();

ch.close();

console.log( ret, ret == Curl.code.CURLE_OK, Easy.strError( ret ) );
```

It's less user friendly however. Since now you need to build the body array and create the headers object yourself.

`HEADERFUNCTION` and `WRITEFUNCTION` callbacks are going to receive the response body and headers chunks, respectively. `buf` is a Node.js `Buffer` object.